# Большие объемы текста в Android Studio

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Как поместить на одно Activity несколько абзацев какого-либо текста и иметь возможность прокрутки этого текста? Если я хочу размещать на одном экране много текста и несколько картинок то какую активность нужно создавать и как вводить этот текст, через gava или xml код?

Comment: **gava**?? Первый раз такое вижу, это гениально! Даже гениальнее, чем *Ява*

Answer (score 2):

Много текста с прокруткой - `TextView`, вложенный в `ScrollView`.

Много текста + картинки + оформление + и т.п. - наилучший вариант создать `html` страницу со всем необходимым и скормить ее `WebView`:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myPage.html");
```

Comment: +1 за `WebVIew`. Очень длинный `TextView` будет тормозить, а если вы туда Войну и мир вставите, то и вовсе упадет с `OutOfMemory`

Comment: @metalurgus, не-не-не! `WebVIew` же тяжёлый... Лучше будет в `ListView` или `RecyclerView` текст отобразить, предварительно его на части разбив... Так и контроля больше и лагов никаких.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ИМХО шкурка выделки не стоит. Не настолько тяжелый, `WebView`, чтобы заморачиваться разбивать текст по кускам.

Comment: @metalurgus, ну, просто лично у меня тормозит даже на 5-10 строчной таблице с двумя колонками. А когда я `WebView` с ней заменил на 10 `TextView` - лаги исчезли...